# What kind of memory is needed for my old PC?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, hardware-detection

Here is the photo of my old PC
[image: pc]

What kind of RAM and HDD are supported there?

From Windows hardware details I found the following:

```
amd athlon 64 x2 dual
core processor 4200+
2,21 GHz 960 Mb RAM

harddrive 160 Гб wd1600aajs-00psa0

NVidia GeForce 6100 nForce 405

NVidia MCP61 Serial ATA Controller
```

Comment: See those markings right in the middle of the motherboard? Those matter.

Comment: That photo is not helpful. As it sound like you're planning on adding RAM, please remove a stick and inspect the label - if you'd like help figuring it out, please take a careful (in focus) photo of the label and share it with su.

Comment: Please also take a good photo of the white text right in the middle of the motherboard - that is probably the model number, which will help us identify the supported RAM and SATA interfaces... sadly there is no AMD version of Intel's ARK...

Comment: @Attie, this PC is ~2000 kms from my home currently and being operated by grandmother - that is why I can not make better pictures or read labels...

Comment: But how does that prevent *her* from doing either of those?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, done finally. This is Gigabyte GA-M61SME-S2L (https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-M61SME-S2L-rev-20#ov)

Comment: "Supports high performance Dual Channel DDR2 800 memory" And there you are. Might have a bit of trouble finding it for a decent price though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four different versions of the Athlon X2 4200+, two of which fit Socket 939 and use DDR1 RAM, and the remainder fit Socket AM2 and use DDR2 RAM.  They all ran at 2.2GHz and are difficult to distinguish from software.

A much more reliable indicator would be the motherboard model number, which isn't visible in the information you've provided.  You should also be able to read the socket type from the engraving on the hinge of the socket, which looks like it's visible just below the edge of the heatsink (but is unreadable in your blurry photo).  If you already have some RAM, you could also read the label of that and buy some more to match.

If it's Socket 939, DDR-400 is your best option.  It should be widely available and cheap by now, whether new or second-hand.  This generation of AMD CPUs likes low latency rather than high bandwidth, so aim for the lowest CL timings you can find while retaining DDR-400 speed.

If it's Socket AM2, DDR2-800 is probably what you should look for, again with the lowest CL timings available in that speed.  DDR2-1066 may also be available, but the CL timings may be significantly looser, which would be counter-productive on this CPU.

As for the HDD, any SATA HDD, SSHD or SSD (in increasing order of performance) should work fine.

Comment: Nitpicking in an otherwise nice answer: 5400rpm SSHDs (and I'm unaware of any other type) do not perform better than 7200rpm HDDs.

Comment: @MichaelBay There are 7200rpm SSHDs: https://pcpartpicker.com/product/NpBrxr/seagate-firecuda-2tb-35-7200rpm-hybrid-internal-hard-drive-st2000dx002

Comment: OK, those should perform slightly better than a traditional 7200rpm HDD. That said, it's mostly a marketing stunt.

Comment: Thanks. I found the motherboard model finally (https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-M61SME-S2L-rev-20#ov), so this is DDR2-800. But I don't see on the photo, does it have one slot available? Are memory slots in yellow color?

Comment: I can not understand what kind of SATA interface is needed for SSD disk. Will WDS120G2G0A (https://support.wdc.com/product.aspx?ID=1801) work?

Comment: The m/board has two RAM slots in total.  Ideally you should put the same RAM in both.  If you buy two DIMMs together (they often come in kits), then you don't need to worry about what might already be there.

Comment: @LA_ SATA is SATA - the various versions are all compatible with each other.  Just make sure your PSU has a suitable SATA-type power connector spare - using a Molex-to-SATA adapter is also okay.  Also think about how to mount a 2.5" drive in that case, which looks like it has 3.5" and 5.25" bays.

Answer (score 1):

I can't distinguish the motherboard model number from your photo (probably the white text in the middle of the board)... but...

It looks like the [nForce 405](http://www.nvidia.com/page/gpumobo_6100-405_features.html) supports SATA 2.0 (aka "*SATA 300*" or "*SATA 3.0Gb/s*").

I was unable to find information on the Athlon 64 x2 4200+ (particularly the memory controller), but I suspect DDR2. Purchasing faster memory shouldn't be an issue (it'll just run slower than it could), and given the age of DDR2, it might be worth just buying some off eBay and giving it a go.

[Sadly there is no AMD equivelent to Intel's ARK...](https://products.amd.com/en-us/search#k=athlon%2064%20x2)